# Is there a way to load a function with a Navigation Link in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to know if there is way to call a function along with a NavigationLink in Swift. I have a detail view for a list of posts but in order to get all of the information for that detailed post view I need to call a fetcher function in order to load a bunch of extra information which I cannot make with the initial call as it would largely increase the time to make the initial request for posts. Something like the following, keep in mind this most definitely isn't how it would look just what I envision as how it would work.

```
List(self.posts) { result in
   NavigationLink(call: PostFetchingFunction(PostID: result.ID) -> destination: DetailedPostView(post: PostFetchingFunction.result)) {
       Text("Go to detailed post view")
   }
}
```

As I said, this, most definitely isn't correct Swift code, but just a code visualization of what I'd like to do might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using a provider pattern conforming to `ObservableObject`

#### 1. ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0...100, id: \.self) { (index) in
                NavigationLink("Show \(index)",
                    destination: NextView(provider: ItemProvider(id: index)))
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
    }
}
```

- Destination is `NextView`
- `NextView` requires something of type `ItemProvider` for it's initialization (we'll see this later)

---

#### 2. NextView

```
struct NextView: View {
    @ObservedObject var provider: ItemProvider

    var body: some View {
        Text(provider.title)
            .navigationBarTitle("Item", displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear {
                self.provider.load()
        }
    }
}
```

- `ItemProvider` is an `@ObservedObject` which makes it a listener for changes in order to update the view
- `.onAppear` is where we run a funtion, in this case `self.provider.load()` to get the `provider` to begin fetching

---

#### 3. ItemProvider

```
class ItemProvider: ObservableObject {
    private var id: Int
    @Published var title: String = ""

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    func load() {
        title = "Loading \(id)"

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            guard let _weakSelf = self else { return }
            _weakSelf.title = "Loaded \(_weakSelf.id)"
        }
    }
}
```

- `ItemProvider` has to conform to `ObservableObject` in order to emit changes
- Any variables within that are marked `@Published` will emit a change signal
- `ItemProvider` has a `load` function that actually does the fetching and if it updates any `@Published` variables, the connected `View`s will be notified and will update automatically